# How to get user home directory on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, home-directory

I'm developing a cross-platform library that is meant to load configuration files from a user's home directory. The idea is to automatically provide configuration parameters without editing code.

This library can be used in desktop apps or in daemons/services. In (I assume) most Unix environments I can use `getpwuid()` to get the home directory of the user. In Windows SO [told me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6827889/70600) I could use [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188.aspx) but its documentation says its for desktop apps only. Is there a way to get this path, on Windows, for the user running a service?

Comment: Services *are* desktop apps.  The clause about "desktop apps only" means you can't use it in, for example, a Windows Phone apps.

Comment: ... of course, you'll get the folders associated with the user account that the service is running in.  That *might* make sense, depending on how the service is configured.  It seems unlikely to be sensible for a library, though; surely the programmer using your library should be setting the parameters, not the end user?

Answer (score 9):

For a console application the simplest method is to either retrieve the `USERPROFILE` environment variable or concatenate the values of the `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` environment variables.

Use the `getenv()` function in the standard library: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tehxacec.aspx

Example program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("USERPROFILE = %s\n", getenv("USERPROFILE"));
    printf("HOMEDRIVE   = %s\n", getenv("HOMEDRIVE"));
    printf("HOMEPATH    = %s\n", getenv("HOMEPATH"));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
USERPROFILE = C:\Users\myuser
HOMEDRIVE   = C:
HOMEPATH    = \Users\myuser
```

Comment: Could those vars be overwritten in a desktop/phone app?

Comment: The user profile is not the right location for configuration files.

Comment: @ruipacheco Doubtful that they'd be overwritten or changed.

Answer (score 2):

What about this:

```
#include <shlobj.h> 

WCHAR profilePath[MAX_PATH];
HRESULT result = SHGetFolderPathW(NULL, CSIDL_PROFILE, NULL, 0, profilePath);
if (SUCCEEDED(result)) {
    // Do whatever you want with it
    // For example:
    // QString::fromWCharArray(profilePath)
}
```

I haven't tested it, though.

Note that what you receive is a wchar array (necessary to handle paths with special characters).

I think it's also possible to query special folders of other users than the current one by using the `hToken` parameter.

Also refer to the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181(v=vs.85).aspx

I used this code in another case where I wanted to obtain the start menu location. See this answer: [C++: How do I create a Shortcut in the Start Menu on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33841911/c-how-do-i-create-a-shortcut-in-the-start-menu-on-windows#answer-33841912)

Comment: No, no, no!  The profile directory is NOT the right place for configuration files.  Try `CSIDL_APPDATA`.

Comment: From what I understood he wanted the user's home directory.

Comment: There's always been [some disagreement](https://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925) about how best to respond when someone asks the wrong question.  I'm firmly in the camp that says you give them the information they need, rather than (or as well as) the information they asked for.

Comment: ... besides, the user's home directory isn't necessarily their profile directory anyway.  That's just the default if the user account settings don't specify a home directory explicitly.  (I'm just nitpicking here, the distinction doesn't really matter, particularly since no modern application should use either the profile directory or the home directory for anything.)

Comment: SHGetFolderPathW seems deprecated

Comment: This is brilliant! Thank you! I've always been wary of relying on environment variables, as they can be changed...

Answer (score 0):

So do you want to get user home directory in service state?
 - If you want that in service state, you have to use `GetUserToken()` to get user token then duplicate them for `CreateprocessAsUser()`
 - Else I think it's better using `SHGetSpecialPath()`, `SHGetTempPath()`.

Comment: Attenzion!! Only can use for desktop apps in ver 5.2 ~ 5.3. - MSDN [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181(v=vs.85).aspx]

Comment: That page is a 404.

Comment: You have to remove last character "]"! I think you're not attenzion on my answer. I won;t type anymore.

Comment: Thank you for all answers! ruipacheco.

Answer (score 0):

You could resolve  %HOMEPATH% using `ExpandEnvironmentStrings(...)`

Comment: That variable doesn't always exist.